# Is there an xclip equivalent to interact with gpm's paste buffer?

Tags: sockets, console, clipboard, xclip, pbcopy

I'm looking for a way to read/write accessing the paste buffer (referred to as "selection" in the manpage) of gpm from commandline, along the lines of how X clipboards can be accessed via xclip. A socket or character device to interface gpm's paste buffer would also be fine. However, I can't seem to find such a device, nor the xclip analogon, nor any relevant commandline option provided by gpm itself.

I've searched and found [suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298084/how-to-output-into-clipboard-and-paste-in-bash-tty) on how the X clipboard can be used with readline in a similar manner as normally the (top entry of the) kill ring is used.

Unlike those though, the gpm solution I'm looking for is more general and not limited to readline editing.